# Prove that $\sum_{x} x \log(x) = \sum_{x'} x' \log(x')$ implies $\sum_{x} x = \sum_{x'} x' $

Tags: summation, logarithms, monotone-functions

I am trying to prove that:

$$
\sum_{x} x \log(x) = \sum_{x'} x' \log(x') \implies \sum_{x} x = \sum_{x'} x'
$$
for $0 \le x, x' \le 1$. I am not sure how to proceed. Can I use the monotonicity of log to prove it? TIA

Comment: Thanks @Martin , I've updated the question.

Comment: Are the sums finite? Also, all the $x,x'$ are positive?

Comment: Thanks @Surb, I've updated the question to include the domain of x.

Comment: Ok, so I guess you use the convention $0\log(0)=0$.? it is also still not clear if the sums are finite.

Comment: Start with considering sums of one term only.

Comment: I doubt that the statement is true ...

Comment: @MartinR Indeed, $x=0$ and $x'=1$ seem to provide a counter example. (assuming $x\log(x)$ is extended by continuity at $0$).

Comment: Trivial counterexample: $x\ln x=x'\ln x'=-\tfrac12\ln2$, $x=\tfrac12,\ x'=\tfrac14$.